# How many pre-configured WAF rules do a small website needs? (GCP Cloud Armor)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, ddos, website, small-business

I am looking at GCP Cloud Armor product. They charge $1 per-rule a month. There is this document with pre-configured rules: https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning

Can you tell how much of it is really necessary for a small website? I don't want to pay 100s for unused rules.

*P.S. although the website is small, there is at least one competitor, who is a malicious person and is almost certainly will try a DDOS attack - this is why I am looking for protection before releasing it, but at an affordable cost**

Comment: Which rules do you need? That depends on your website and traffic patterns. When I deploy Cloud Armor, I usually enable the rules one at a time and then monitor blocked traffic. Typically, I only enable six of the ten rules plus several custom ones that I write. However, you are focussing on the wrong item. Cloud Armor rules will often save you money. How much should you spend? That depends on what you are protecting.

Comment: can I just cover ddos for now? can it be done with one rule? rate of requests or something?

Comment: DDoS is built into HTTP(S) Load Balancer + Cloud Armor. If you are concerned about the price of one rule - $1.00, then you probably have a small instance, small disks, small database, etc. That design would fall over quickly. DDoS means many things when you get to the backends handling that traffic. As my comment said, everything depends. You will need to deploy, test, measure, and monitor to know how effective your architecture is.

Comment: yeah `small` is in the title :) I am concerned to not pay what I dont need but I dont know what I need hence the merry go round.. but never mind. I get it.. its for real mccoys only. Ill go back and polish my small caliber revolver